# Analytics custom vars in a Google Site

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-sites

Is it possible to register a custom var in a google site? I've been trying for a week and still can't get it.

I know there are two ways to do this.

- Async: this is recommended by analytics docs, but it doesn't work because gSites doesn't allow to add a node dynamically using DOM. I tried a lot of times...

  `_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',    4, 'customVar4', "cuatro", 2 ]);`
  `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`
- Sync: I can't make this work, it tries to use _gat object before it is ready (or fully loaded) and end with an error.

  `var tracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXX-X");`

  `tracker._setCustomVar(2,"tracker2","mail",1);`

  `pageTracker._trackPageview();`

Can anybody help me? **the problem is in google sites only, creating an app script, and adding it as a gadget.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As described in [this help page](http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2500646&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=1jsv9tss5vkzm&cbrank=4)

1. Go to the Google Sites page that you’d like to embed HTML in.
2. Go to the Insert menu and select HTML Box.
3. In the dialog that opens, add HTML, CSS and/or Javascript code.
4. Now you can insert your `<script>` tag

Try to add the common code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_gaq.push(function() {
    var tracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
    tracker._setCustomVar(1, 'Feedback', 'Closed', 1);
    tracker._trackPageview();
});
</script>
```

I also recommend you to check the [Google Analytic's devguide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration).

Comment: I can't do what I need in a HTML Box, I need an app script. I need script.gs to retrieve data from a scriptDB, and then from the .gs file I import the html with the script on it using data provided by de .gs script.

Comment: you can add script tags using HTML Box, I just tested. It will also format the text while you are typing, you can't when you use the edit html source button.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking

Comment: I know that this is how I should define a custom var , but in google sites this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Since Google Sites doesn't allow dynamic insertion, just add the script explicitly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 4, 'customVar4', "cuatro", 2 ]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

</script>
```

Comment: It could also just be impossible looking into it a little more. From  http://www.steegle.com/websites/google-sites-howtos/google-analytics - apparently Google Sites automatically removes all `<script>` tags automatically and you can just use plain tracking.